stack different columns within dataframe with overlapping values
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4), y1=c('a','a','a',NA), y2=c(NA,NA,'b','b'))

  x   y1   y2
  1    a <NA>
  2    a <NA>
  3    a    b  --> a and b share the same value of 3
  4 <NA>    b

I'm trying to stack y1 and y2 into a new y column such that each non-NA value of y1 and y2 gets its corresponding x value.
The output should look like:
 x    y
 1    a
 2    a
 3    a
 3    b
 4    b

3 is repeated because it appears both in a and b.
I tried bind_rows from dplyr but it seems to work only for different data frames.

With tidyr::pivot_longer():
(df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4), y1=c('a','a','a',NA), y2=c(NA,NA,'b','b')))
#>   x   y1   y2
#> 1 1    a <NA>
#> 2 2    a <NA>
#> 3 3    a    b
#> 4 4 <NA>    b

tidyr::pivot_longer(df, y1:y2, names_to = NULL, values_to = "y",  values_drop_na = TRUE) 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>       x y    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 a    
#> 2     2 a    
#> 3     3 a    
#> 4     3 b    
#> 5     4 b

Created on 2024-09-20 with reprex v2.1.1

In base R, we can try
df = data.frame(x = rep(df$x, 2L), y = c(df$y1, df$y2)) 
df[complete.cases(df), ]

giving
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 a
3 3 a
7 3 b
8 4 b

or
reshape(df2, idvar="x", direction="long", varying=2:3, v.names="y") |>
  na.omit() |>
  subset(select=-time)

giving
    x y
1.1 1 a
2.1 2 a
3.1 3 a
3.2 3 b
4.2 4 b


Note
Assuming the corrected data looks like:
df = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4), y1=c('a','a','a',NA), y2=c(NA,NA,'b','b'))


You can try the following base R option
na.omit(
  data.frame(
    x = rep(df$x, each = ncol(df) - 1),
    y = c(t(df[-1]))
  )
)

which gives
  x y
1 1 a
3 2 a
5 3 a
6 3 b
8 4 b

or you can use melt from data.table package
melt(
  as.data.table(df),
  id.vars = "x", 
  measure.vars = patterns("^y"), 
  na.rm = TRUE
)[, variable := NULL][]

which gives
       x  value
   <num> <char>
1:     1      a
2:     2      a
3:     3      a
4:     3      b
5:     4      b


Benchmarking (if you are interested)
f1 <- \() {
  na.omit(
    data.frame(
      x = rep(df$x, each = ncol(df) - 1),
      y = c(t(df[-1]))
    )
  )
}

f2 <- \() {
  melt(
    as.data.table(df),
    id.vars = "x",
    measure.vars = patterns("^y"),
    na.rm = TRUE
  )[, variable := NULL][]
}

f3 <- \() {
  reshape(df, idvar = "x", direction = "long", varying = -1, v.names = "y") |>
    na.omit() |>
    subset(select = -time)
}

f4 <- \() {
  pivot_longer(df, -x, names_to = NULL, values_to = "y", values_drop_na = TRUE)
}

shows
Unit: relative
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
   f1  5.449224  5.518103  3.300644  5.284431  3.145165 1.406583   100
   f2  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000   100
   f3 59.959643 62.601574 27.306060 52.955219 24.412296 5.956766   100
   f4  2.583836  2.358395  1.797496  2.766277  1.459398 1.275078   100

Given dummy data
set.seed(0)
v <- c(NA, letters)
n <- 1e5
df <- cbind(
  x = 1:n,
  setNames(
    as.data.frame(replicate(5, sample(v, n, replace = TRUE))),
    paste0("y", 1:5)
  )
)


@lroha good point, see my update

What makes f1() so slow (in comparison)? t()?  na.omit() could be easily replaced.

@Friede I guess both t() and na.omit()

Well I think df = data.frame(x = rep(df$x, 2L), y = c(df$y1, df$y2)); df[complete.cases(df),  ] is faster, although not faster than data.table.

@Friede but I don't think c(df$y1, df$y2)  works as expected if y2's first element is not NA.
